# JavaFX8 mediaplayer plays video on OS X but not on Windows 7

Tags: java, javafx

I am struggling some with the JavaFX Mediaplayer. I have a few videos that is mp4(h264 and aac), and it plays well on my Mac, but it does not play on any of my Windows PCs. It does not throw any errors, it just does not play. The screen goes white, thats it. Is there any particular reason for this? I am calling "mediaPlayer.play()", and I the Media Feature Pack for Windows is installed. Thanks in advance.

```
String path = Settings.currentDir() + File.separator + "files" + File.separator + filename;
Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(false);
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
mediaView.setFitWidth(width);
mediaView.setFitHeight(height);
mediaPlayer.setMute(true);

StackPane borderPane = new StackPane();
borderPane.setMinSize(width, height);
borderPane.getChildren().add(mediaView);
```

Comment: Please show the code that creates your `Media` instance, including any code that builds the string passed to the Media constructor.

Comment: Updated my question with code

Comment: How sure are you that the file exists on Windows?  Perhaps it would be useful to print out the value returned by `Files.isReadable(Paths.get(path))`?

Comment: I got an error when testing more today, which is ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID. Which seems to be because that the video is larger than 1920x1080 in resolution, at least in width.